# Understanding Elasticsearch Bool query

Tags: elasticsearch

I am porting ( from ES 1.3 to ES 6) old query API's to use new Rest High Level Client APIshave following questions regarding the two queries mentioned below

1. Are both the queries same. If not what is the difference ?
2. If both queries are different, should I use the first query for and operation and to replicate the old AndFilterBuilder logic ( ES version 1.3 )

First Query :

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : [
            {
              "exists" : {
                "field" : "test",
                "boost" : 1.0
              }
            },
            {
              "term" : {
                "key" : {
                  "value" : "value",
                  "boost" : 1.0
                }
              }
            }
          ],
          "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Second Query :

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "filter" : [
      {
        "exists" : {
          "field" : "test",
          "boost" : 1.0
        }
      },
      {
        "term" : {
          "key" : {
            "value" : "value",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "adjust_pure_negative" : true,
    "boost" : 1.0
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you require scoring?

If scoring is being ignored they are the same and I would use `filter` over `must` as that makes it eligible for caching.

If scoring is required, use `must`.

Elasticsearch documentation explains it in this way:

> A query clause used in query context answers the question “How well does this document match this query clause?”
>
> In filter context, a query clause answers the question “Does this document match this query clause?” The answer is a simple Yes or No — no scores are calculated.

`must` uses query context, `filter` uses filter context.

Comment: Thanks for the input @hudsonb. In the first query also `must` is inside a `filter`. Does not it make the first query also use filter context ?

Comment: Yes, the first query will be filter context because of the top-level `filter`. I prefer the second query, as it is more compact.